# Changing the type of last_activity column when using database session storage in Laravel 5

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, session, laravel-5

I've just started using the `database` session driver in Laravel 5.5 along with PostgreSQL, and I've ran into a slight inconvenience.

I would like to keep the `last_activity` column as `timestamp with timezone`, but Laravel wants to write an integer into it, and it sometimes also attempts to delete from it based on an integer value.

I tried doing the following in my `Session` model:

```
public function setLastActivityAttribute($ts){
    $this->attributes['last_activity'] = date('c', $ts);
}
```

which works well for saving, but when Laravel tries to garbage collect the sessions it uses an integer value which causes a `PDOException`:

> SQLSTATE[22008]: Datetime field overflow: 7 ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "1506794381"
>   HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting. (SQL: delete from "sessions" where "last_activity" <= 1506794381)

Is there any way I could specify a format or intercept the process to keep the `timestamptz` column type?

Comment: Why the `with timezone`? The values are unix timestamps and without timezone information.

Comment: @sisve In graphical environments like Adminer or the CLI `timestamptz` displays as a human-readable value in my own timezone, whereas an integer is less obvious at a glance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest creating a custom session driver by overwriting the `gc` and `expired` methods of the [`DatabaseSessionHandler.php`](https://github.com/illuminate/session/blob/master/DatabaseSessionHandler.php) driver to work with `timestamp with timezone` instead of integers.

The `gc` currently passes `time() - $lifetime` but you can change this to `date('c', time() - $lifetime)`. And in `expired` you can call `strtotime` on `$session->last_activity` to convert to the same unit as `getTimestamp()`.

```
<?php

namespace App\Extensions;
use Illuminate\Session\DatabaseSessionHandler;

class MyPostgresHandler extends DatabaseSessionHandler
{   
    public function gc($lifetime) {
        $sessions = $this->getQuery()->where('last_activity', '<=', date('c', time() - $lifetime))->get();
        foreach ($sessions as $session) {
            $this->destroy($session->id);
        }
    }

    protected function expired($session)
    {
        return isset($session->last_activity) &&
            strtotime($session->last_activity) < Carbon::now()->subMinutes($this->minutes)->getTimestamp();
    }
}
```

Then you can register your new driver by extending `ServiceProvider`

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Extensions\MyPostgresHandler;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class SessionServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Perform post-registration booting of services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Session::extend('my-db-driver', function ($app) {
            return new MyPostgresHandler;
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register bindings in the container.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Now you can use `my-db-driver` in `config/session.php`

For more info see https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/session#implementing-the-driver

**Update from OP**

Adding on top of [FuzzyTree's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46509436/1344955), there's some more code that needs to be added than what the docs say, so I wanted to post the rest of the process. Because we're extending the built-in class it has some ties to other parts of the framework, but thankfully there are ways to tap into them. The final SessionServiceProvider looks like this:

```
namespace App\Providers;

use App\Extensions\MyPostgresHandler;
use Illuminate\Database\Connectors\PostgresConnector;
use Illuminate\Database\PostgresConnection;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Database\Connection;

class SessionServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
    public function boot(){
        Session::extend('postgres', function ($app){
            return new MyPostgresHandler;
        });
        Connection::resolverFor('postgres', function ($connection, $database, $prefix, $config) {
            return new PostgresConnection($connection, $database, $prefix, $config);
        });
        $this->app->bind('db.connector.postgres', function(){
            return new PostgresConnector;
        });
    }
}
```

I've named my driver `postgres` and the driver's class is identical to what's in the original answer. My IDE was showing an error on the `return new MyPostgresHandler;` line due to missing parameters, but it seems like the code works regardless.

These resolvers are necessary for the rest of Laravel to accept our new driver because the built-in classes only map the `pgsql` name to the appropriate classes, and since we've made a driver with a different name it will deem it invalid otherwise.

Finally, the service provider has to be registered in `config/app.php`:

```
'providers' => [
    // ...

    /*
     * Application Service Providers...
     */
    App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,

    App\Providers\SessionServiceProvider::class, // <--
],
```